# pass value to servlet from jsp by hyperlink

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

I saw answers relating to this question and tried to solve still I am getting null in Servlet, where I am doing mistake?? Perhaps I am missing something in Javascript or in jsp??

### home.jsp

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="layout/styles/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

      function callMe(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/NewServlet",
  data: { methodToInvoke: "sayHello" , data: "4" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}  
        </script>
```

I want to pass the value **4** to servlet(doPost in NewServlet.java) from home.jsp

```
<a href="NewServlet?count=4" onclick="callMe()" id="4" >HTML Images</a>
```

### NewServlet.java

```
 String t= request.getParameter("count");
           out.println(t);// should display 4, but getting null here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `count=4` in the url of your ajax request

```
function callMe(count){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/NewServlet?count=" + count,
  data: { methodToInvoke: "sayHello" , data: "4" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
```

and in your jsp:

```
<a  onclick="callMe(4)" id="4" >HTML Images</a>
```

**Edit**:
To send the count back to the webbrowser, do:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(t);
```

where response is a `HttpServletResponse` .

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) to get started

Comment: still null coming, <a href="NewServlet?count=4" onclick="callMe(4)" id="4" >HTML Images</a>

Comment: any js file to be added or any modification required in jsp??

Comment: If you use, for example,  `out.println("count = " + t); `, and you see in the console `count = `, it means that you are entering the method and you dont need anything to be added

Comment: Also, try from the webbrowser to go to `http://localhost:8080/NewServlet?count=4 ` (or whatever machine/port you use) and see if you can see some output

Comment: ya thnx I am getting in d browser url that count=4 but how can I print it in out.println(); ??

Comment: Your servlet method should return a string and your ajax script should pop up the alert with `msg` set

Comment: ok but I do n't want servlet to return anything only it should print 4 which will be shown in the browser

Comment: ya I sent to a jsp page, it worked thnx but in servlet still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name is "count" not "param1" ..
So, It should be:

```
String t = request.getParameter("count");
```

Comment: I have modified to count still no result getting null